# Why does WebApiController serialise booleans as 'true' and 'false' in JSON?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, serialization

I have a requirement to shrink the JSON serialised output as much as possible. It seems quite inefficient that the built in WebApi serialiser converts a bit value into 8-10 byte (16-20 if Unicode) representations 'true' or 'false'. Is there a simpler way it can be made more efficient than for example re-declaring my bools as int's to get it as 0 and 1?

Comment: Because that is the standard of JSON for booleans: http://json.org/

Comment: Formats like XML and JSON are not made to produce the most compact representation, but to obtain a human-readable way. Instead of shrinking the JSON, perhaps using [**BSON**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSON) is a better idea.

Comment: JSON does not have **Types**, everything is a string. I would proceed with the 0/1 conversion